# How do you pass object in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
const { screen } = data;
// screen = 'News', string
const { params } = data;
// params = object
// Object {
  "body": "test",
  "created_at": "2020-05-25 21:25:37",
  "status": 1,
  "title": "test",
  "updated_at": "2020-05-25 21:25:37",
}
if (notification.origin === 'selected') {
  if (screen) {
    NavigationService.navigate(screen, { params });
  }
}
```

```js
function navigate(routeName, object) {
  console.log('routeName =' + routeName);
  // routeName =News
  console.log(object);
  // Object {
       "params": null,
     }
}
```

**problem**

I can't get object in `function navigate`.

I don't still understand it..
I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Comment: can you add more code to see exactly what's your problem

Comment: Are you asking about `[object Object]`? Since you have `+` with a string, the `toString()` method is called on the object. Try with `console.log('object =' + JSON.stringify(object))` or just `console.log(object)`

Comment: @adiga when I just ```console.log(object);```, it returns ```Object {
  "params": null,
}```.

Comment: Can you log `console.log(params)` before calling `navigate` and check it's value? Also, is this all your code or do you have any asynchronous code you have omitted to post here?

Comment: @adiga It returns ```// Object {
  "body": "test",
  "created_at": "2020-05-25 21:25:37",
  "status": 1,
  "title": "test",
  "updated_at": "2020-05-25 21:25:37",
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add the brackets around `param` when calling `navigate`. Call it like so:

```js
NavigationService.navigate(screen, params);
```

Instead of:

```js
NavigationService.navigate(screen, { params });
```